# GWTP nested tab presenter

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am trying to nest a tab presenter in GWTP. I have one frame (North) that is tab group 1 and one frame (West) that is tab group 2. When I interact with group 1 I update the nested tab presenter which controls group 2. I have looked at the example for nested tab presenters but I have been unable to determine my error from it.

The two TabContainerPresenters are ManagmentTabsPresenter and SettingsTabsPresenter. The children of these are like the HomePresenter below. The content for these children is displayed in the center of a DockLayoutPanel. I want the ManagementTabsPresenter and the SettingsTabsPresenter to be displayed in the West slot of the same DockLayoutPanel.

The problem as I see it is that when this code is run the revealInParent() method of the ManagementTabsPresenter and the revealInParent() method of the SettingsTabsPresenter are both called whenever I try to view one on the child tabs. (i.e. homePresenter). Why are both of these revealInParent methods called? What am I missing? It is true that both SettingsTabsPresenter and ManagementTabsPresenter are in a parent tab that gets revealed. Does this mean that the revealInParent of both of these tabcontainerprestners(nonleavetabcontentproxy) will be called when the parent tabcontainerpreseter is revelatedinparent?

```
public class HomePresenter extends Presenter<HomePresenter.MyView, HomePresenter.MyProxy> {
@Inject
AppPlaceManager appPlaceManager;

@NameToken(NameTokens.homePage)
@ProxyStandard
@NoGatekeeper
public interface MyProxy extends TabContentProxyPlace<HomePresenter> {
}

public interface MyView extends View {
}

@TabInfo(container = ManagementTabsPresenter.class)
static TabData getTabLabel(MainAppGinjector injector) {
    return new TabDataBasic(injector.getVSMMessages().home_tab(), ClientConstants.HOME_TAB_POSITION);
}

@Inject
public HomePresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view, final MyProxy proxy) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);
}

@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this, ManagementTabsPresenter.TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT, this);
}
}





public class ManagementTabsPresenter extends TabContainerPresenter<ManagementTabsPresenter.MyView, ManagementTabsPresenter.MyProxy> {

/**
 * {@link ManagementTabsPresenter}'s proxy.
 */
@ProxyStandard
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<ManagementTabsPresenter> {
}

/**
 * {@link ManagementTabsPresenter}'s view.
 */
public interface MyView extends TabView {
}

/**
 * Fired by child proxie's when their tab content is changed.
 */
@ChangeTab
public static final Type<ChangeTabHandler> TYPE_Management_ChangeTab = new Type<ChangeTabHandler>();

/**
 * Use this in leaf presenters, inside their {@link #revealInParent} method.
 */
@ContentSlot
public static final GwtEvent.Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT = MainPresenter.CENTER_SLOT;


/**
 * This will be the event sent to our "unknown" child presenters, in order for
 * them to register their tabs.
 */
@RequestTabs
public static final Type<RequestTabsHandler> TYPE_Management_RequestTabs = new Type<RequestTabsHandler>();

@Inject
public ManagementTabsPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view,
                               final MyProxy proxy,  AppPlaceManager appPlaceManager) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy,TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT, TYPE_Management_RequestTabs, TYPE_Management_ChangeTab);
}


@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this,  MainPresenter.WEST_SLOT, this);
}
}



public class SettingsTabsPresenter extends TabContainerPresenter<SettingsTabsPresenter.MyView, SettingsTabsPresenter.MyProxy> {

/**
 * {@link SettingsTabsPresenter}'s proxy.
 */
@ProxyStandard
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<SettingsTabsPresenter> {
}

/**
 * {@link SettingsTabsPresenter}'s view.
 */
public interface MyView extends TabView {
}

/**
 * Fired by child proxie's when their tab content is changed.
 */
@ChangeTab
public static final Type<ChangeTabHandler> TYPE_Settings_ChangeTab = new Type<ChangeTabHandler>();

/**
 * Use this in leaf presenters, inside their {@link #revealInParent} method.
 */
@ContentSlot
public static final GwtEvent.Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT = MainPresenter.CENTER_SLOT;


/**
 * This will be the event sent to our "unknown" child presenters, in order for
 * them to register their tabs.
 */
@RequestTabs
public static final Type<RequestTabsHandler> TYPE_Settings_RequestTabs = new Type<RequestTabsHandler>();

@Inject
public ManagementTabsPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view,
                               final MyProxy proxy,  AppPlaceManager appPlaceManager) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy,TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT, TYPE_Settings_RequestTabs, TYPE_Settings_ChangeTab);
}


@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this,  MainPresenter.WEST_SLOT, this);
}
}




public class MainPresenter extends Presenter<MainPresenter.MyView, MainPresenter.MyProxy>{

@Inject VSMRequestFactory requestFactory;
@Inject VSMMessages vsmMessages;
@Inject VSMExceptionMessages vsmExceptionMessages;
@Inject EventBus eventBus;

@ProxyStandard
@NoGatekeeper
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<MainPresenter> {
}

public interface MyView extends View {

}

@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> SOUTH_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();
@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> WEST_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();
@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> CENTER_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();
@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> NORTH_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();

@Inject
public MainPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);
}

@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealRootLayoutContentEvent.fire(this, this);
}

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    initializeAppUser();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a piece of code or link that you are following ?

Comment: So I think the problem is in what I am trying to do here. I want the two panels on the west to only be displayed when they are active. It seems that GWTP wants to make them visible always. How can I make one stay hidden?

Answer (score 0):

It should be an event issue, when you select a tab, SelectionEvent may be consumed by the wrong tab. Could you add some code about tab initialization?

Comment: The Selection Event is being consumed by the wrong tab. Both revealinparent methods for each tabcontainer is being fired. I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Events have a source parameter, you can rely on this when consuming the event, getting it back with getSource(). say a click on a tab set itself as source, then children view can ensure where the change event comes from

Comment: Yes I agree with that. But where can I get this SelectionEvent from? My code is above there.

Comment: Hi so I tried this approach and it is not that the selectionevent is being consumed by the wrong tab. The problem is that the selection event is being fired on all nested tab presenters and not just the one in which it is contained.